# Launch multiple instances of application in Mac

Tags: macos

I tried with LSMultipleInstancesProhibited = FALSE, in Info.plist, but it is opening one instance,

I need to launch multiple instances of application from one installation directory on Mac

Answer (score 54):

Open Terminal and type:

**open -n -a "APPLICATION NAME"**

Comment: On double clicking the application icon, It should always launch in new instance.

Comment: This works even with applications like filezilla that are locked to one instance.

Comment: It works with above command. But  I need it to Launch on Double clicking application icon

Comment: You right, I just tried: Android Studio kills the second instance. 

But you really need it? It can open multiple project at once

Comment: Double clicking did not work for me on 10.14.2, but the command did work.

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot!

Comment: didn't work for Pycharm. it opens and gets killed instantly

Comment: What if the two instances have two different settings scenarios? For example, run two instances of Microsoft Teams each logged in to a different account? Thanks.

Comment: Does not work for all applications

Comment: Works for me. Is it possible to switch between instances with `cmd-\``?

Answer (score 5):

terminal:

open -n -a APPLICATION-NAME

-n, --new Open a new instance of the application even if one is already running.

-a, -- Opens with the specified application.

[How to Launch GUI Applications from the Terminal](http://osxdaily.com/2007/02/01/how-to-launch-gui-applications-from-the-terminal/)

http://osxdaily.com/2007/02/01/how-to-launch-gui-applications-from-the-terminal/