# Allow multiple instances to run from the same logged in user for Mac application

Tags: xcode, macos

I have tried to set `Application prohibits multiple instances` to NO and to YES in Info.plist.  Neither was working.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Launch multiple instances of application in Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350555/launch-multiple-instances-of-application-in-mac)

Comment: @Willeke, No, I was looking into a way to do it within app’s configuration that required no user intervention.  Unless there is no way?